# Which javascript graphs / chart library?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, d3.js, highcharts

I started searching for a good javascript library that could help me to create dynamic graphs and charts from JSON data also using angularJS. But during my research I have come across a lot of names. I wanted to get a professional opinion on which library do you think it better suited for creating dynamic graphs which can updated by users through forms or any other way. Just looking for your professional opinion.

Some of the names I've come across are:

1. D3.js
2. HighCharts.js
3. Charts.js

and few others.

thanks in advance.
Regards,

Syed

Comment: If you still need a more in-depth recommendation, try the [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) stack.

Comment: @Chloe SR mod here. Please make sure to add a link to our [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/46) - we require much more information than an average question here contains. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chartjs is opensource

I have used [Fusioncharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/download/) free version and found that to be awesome

Comment: thank you for your answer. Have you used it with angularJS? In your opinion would it be a good choice for creating a dashboard system. I am just trying to get a professional advice. Again thanks for replying.

Comment: I have used that with jQuery, but angular wont be a problem as long as u have data to feed in. Try out fusioncharts its quite simple and straight forward

Comment: Thank you @vignesh I will defiantly try it out. I going to create a JSON api to feed the data in through angularJS. hopefully that will help.

Comment: If you are using chartjs you might find this handy
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18416773/848841

Comment: Great!! thats vert helpful. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the question is if you want to code the charting yourself or not since D3.js itself is not a charting library, it is much more powerful, low level and flexible, but you have to write everything yourself from scratch. There are some examples, but still, anything custom will take time and you have to know the library to make any change.

Highcharts on the other hand is a complete solution with all charts built-in and enterprise support if you can afford it. Highcharts (and highstock for that matters) is plug, configure, and play, but read license terms and definitions first - they are not obvious.

Charts.js looks simple and elegant, share your experiences please if you choose this one :)

Comment: I do want to code my own charts and graphs as that will give more control over them. Thank you for your answer it was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with angularJS at all, but I have worked extensively with Highcharts and find it to be the best overall charting package available.

D3.js is the way to go if you plan to do a lot of heavy duty custom visualization work of a type that isn't supported by other libraries, but if you want a diverse selection of out-of-the-box visualization types that are still highly customizable, you can't beat Highcharts.

The downside is that it is only free for limited circumstances, but the license fee is very reasonable for a commercial project.